# Monitoring all load balancer in octavia openstack with Prometheus

Tags: load-balancing, openstack

Following https://docs.openstack.org/octavia/latest/user/guides/monitoring.html,
Octavia creates a Listener with protocol PROMETHEUS and metric endpoint is `http://<VIP_address>:<port>/metrics`, so Prometheus server must have connection to VIP address. I want to deploy a Prometheus server monitor all load balancer, which created run in self-service networks. I don't have solution for Prometheus has connection to all load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is added in the Openstack Yoga version. For your situation, I don't get the exact problem but your VIP must be visible to the Prometheus server for that reason maybe it is better to deploy the Prometheus Server outside of the OpenStack cluster or at least make your VIP visible.

Now if your VIP of the load balancer is not visible for Prometheus Server it is another scenario and you should provide more info on your infra to get help. Do you provide valid IP or not? If you deploy the Prometheus server on one Virtual network you should add a route to see the VIP subnet network...